# How to redirect all external request to host file

Tags: redirect, networking, windows-10, reverse-proxy, windows-server-2016

I have gone through many articles and found that the host file will redirect requests from within a server but not the requests coming from another server.

I want to redirect all the requests like HTTP, RDC et...

I have 3 windows servers A, B, C.

I cant send requests from A to C directly because there is no connection between them.
A can send requests to B. B can send request to C.

I have configured the host file in
B to send all related host requests to C.
A to send all related host request to B.

But this will not work if I am sending a request from A.

I cannot access the router and network. I want to know is there any way I can redirect all related host requests to from A to B, B to C. so that A to C should work.

I have heard that some netsh command you can configure so please guide me in a proper way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A host file does not redirect requests. Have you looked ar DNS?

Comment: Actually I don't have access to DNS I need to do everything inside the server. Are there any alternatives that will work as same as the host file. where I can map a specific domain to IP.